# What should I do to avoid an edit war when someone rolls my edits back?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

I typically edit before close voting / flagging / down voting because then I get to read thoroughly and see just how much effort they put in. In this case I did the same, then (mistakenly) close voted because I believed it was a duplicate. It wasn't but before I removed the vote the OP rolled back. I unrolled and then commented, asking. They explained and we sorted it out:

[image]

Another time, the OP and I may not be able to sort it out to easily. How can I make sure to not let it get to revision 6, and to prevent a war happening? Should I not unroll? Because that would leave a bad post. But I don't want a war...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### Step 0. Don't get in an edit war.

The very *first* time somebody deliberately rolls back your edit (I'm not talking about accidental overwriting), leave them a comment asking what's going on and explain your edit. If the edit is urgent push it again, if it's not, wait.

If they can't be reasoned with, flag it up and we'll take a look and take a firmer approach (with whomever needs it).

Chasing after each other is a great way to start a long-term animosity. Please don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Flag the question/answer and tell your partner in crime that you have flagged it.
2. Cool down, take a deep breath and don't forget this is a site with different opinions.
3. If neither of the preceding help you, open a question on meta.

Comment: _"this is only the internet."_ What!? :P

Comment: Rules of the Internet No 71: The Internet is SERIOUS FOOKING BUSINESS.

Comment: Point taken. The internet is also part of social life.